# Ifelse with upper and lower intervals

Tags: r

I have a vector **`x<-rnorm(100)`**

I would like to apply the following condition:

```
if any element of x is larger than 2    -> 1.

if any element of x is smaller than -2  -> -1.

otherwise keep x.
```

I tried:

```
ifelse(x>2,1, ifelse(x<-2,-1),x))
```

but this doesn't seem to work.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your brackets are misplaced. They should all be at the end.

Comment: you mean: ifelse(x>2,1, ifelse(x<-2),-1,x))? this still doesn't work

Comment: He means `ifelse(x>2, 1, ifelse(x<-2,-1,x)))`

Comment: Be careful with your spacing here.  If you don't put a space between the lesser than and negative sign in `x< -2` you are actually assigning `x` to 2.  I've had unfortunate run-ins with this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the `ifelse` statement is `ifelse(condition, true, false)`. You want your second `ifelse` in the `false` position, so put the full `ifelse` there:

```
ifelse(x>2, 1, ifelse(x<-2,-1,x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer has been answered, but I think it's best to avoid nesting multiple `ifelse()` calls if possible (although two isn't too bad). I would restructure what you're doing and say return anything in the interval [-2, 2] unchanged, otherwise return `-1` or `1` as appropriate.

```
ifelse(x >= -2 & x <= 2, x, sign(x))
```

`sign()` will give `-1` for negative numbers and `1` for positives.